# What is the Difference between amd.js file & main.js file in a dist folder of Javascript node project

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, amd

Question is related to javascript project which uses node and web pack.
I see in my current project there is  node_module -> lib folder , there is `xyz.js file in lib folder`.
And in dist folder of node_module there is `xyz.amd.js & xyz.main.js & respective js.map`
I would like to know what is difference between amd & main.js files
And how the Current project which contains this node_module folder uses these files.

```
If you can point me to any site/tutorial explaining these. it would be helpfull
```

Comment: I am not sure who closed this Question and what is the reason?

Answer (score 1):

node.js will load those modules from local the node_modules/ directorywhen it encounters statements such as:

```
var xyz = require("xyz");
```

Or

```
import xyz from 'xyz';
```

"amd" refers to the Asynchronous Module Definition API, which loads modules in a lazy fashion (i.e. as needed).  I suspect your xyz.amd.js module is for the AMD loader.

https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD

Comment: Hey thanks for replay. I got it that amd files represent AMD module, what doest main.js files represt? Is it commonJs modules? aand why do all type of files present in the dist folder instead of any one type of file. If you can explain in more detail, that wud be helpfull